# sys.argv in Python: index out of range message instead of my error message

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, sys

Normally I run this script fro the command line with one argument:
python myscript.py argument

But when this argument is lacking, I want the error message to be shown:

usage: myscript.py [file ...]

Script:

```
import sys
from lxml import etree

filename = sys.argv[1]

tree = etree.parse(filename)

def f1():
...
def main():
   if len(sys.argv) < 2:
           print 'usage: extract.py [file ...]'
           sys.exit(1)

   else:
      f1()
```

Before I had this working, I could the error message in case there is no argument, but now it stopped working, I don't see why... 
I only get this message when I run the script without the argument from the command line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 14, in <module>
    filename = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `filename = sys.argv[1]` runs *first*. Your `len()` test is not reached.

Move setting the `filename` and `tree` into the `main()` function, and don't use globals here:

```
def f1(tree):
    ...

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print 'usage: extract.py [file ...]'
        sys.exit(1)

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    tree = etree.parse(filename)

    f1(tree)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

As Martijn says, `sys.argv[1]` gets referenced before you test `len()`.

I prefer to move the tests into the calling clause instead of main, like so:

```
import sys
from lxml import etree

def f1(tree):
    pass

def main(filename):
    tree = etree.parse(filename)
    f1(tree)

if __name__=="__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        main(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        print 'usage: extract.py [file ...]'
        sys.exit(1)
```

I feel this provides a more logical division of responsibilities in the code.

Answer (score 1):

rather than doing all this why not use `argparse` module from python. If the argument is not provided it will automatically print the usage statement as below

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
args = parser.parse_args()      
print(args.file)
```

`type=argparse.FileType('r')` argument is not necessary but it is better to use.

`'r'` represents and checks whether the file is readable or exists.

Similarly you can use `'w'` to check if file that you are passing is writable.

Output:

> $> python progargs.py
>
> usage: progargs.py [-h] file
>
> progargs.py: error: too few arguments
>
> $> python progargs.py testanotherprog.py
>
> 'testanotherprog.py', mode 'r' at 0x7fe8ee422270>